# Swig wrapper for class inheriting from specialized template type results in missing methods

Tags: c++, swig

I'm using Swig 1.4.1 to wrap some C++ code for a C# project.
Consider the following code which is in one file **Foo.h**.

```
#ifndef __Foo__
#define __Foo__

namespace Ogre
{
    template<int foo, typename T> class FooBase
    {
    public:

        int getFooBase() const
        {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    struct FooSpecialized : public FooBase<4, double>
    {
        int getFooSpecialized() const
        {
            return 2;
        }
    };

    class FooImpl : public FooSpecialized
    {
    public:
        int getFooImpl() const
        {
            return 3;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

For that I use the following in my Swig interface file.

```
%include "Foo.h"
```

As a result of that, I'm getting access to the methods `getFooSpecialized()` and `getFooImpl()`. But `getFooBase()` is missing.

I get **no warnings** when compiling my Swig interface file.

That can easily be seen by looking at the genrated C# files. There is one file **FooSpecialized.cs** which contains

```
public class FooSpecialized : global::System.IDisposable {
  ...

  public int getFooFooSpecialized() {
    int ret = OgrePINVOKE.FooSpecialized_getFooFooSpecialized(swigCPtr);
    if (OgrePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw OgrePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }
}
```

and **FooImpl.cs** which contains

```
public class FooImpl : FooSpecialized {
  ...

  public int getFooImpl() {
    int ret = OgrePINVOKE.FooImpl_getFooImpl(swigCPtr);
    if (OgrePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw OgrePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }
}
```

I tried `%rename` and `%template` so far but it's not working.
I also read about splitting the file, but that is no option for me, because it's a third party component I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the use and position of `%template`.  Use your `Foo.h` as is, the following `test.i` file works:

```
%module test

%{
#include "Foo.h"    // Adds Foo.h to the generated code.
%}

// Declare to SWIG the FooBase class interface.
namespace Ogre
{
    template<int foo, typename T> class FooBase
    {
    public:
        int getFooBase() const;
    };

// Now that SWIG knows the template, declare an instantiation of
// the template you want to use.
%template(FooBase4dbl) FooBase<4,double>;

// Declare the class interfaces that uses the template instance

    struct FooSpecialized : public FooBase<4, double>
    {
        int getFooSpecialized() const;
    };

    class FooImpl : public FooSpecialized
    {
    public:
        int getFooImpl() const;
    };
}
```

If you are willing you can refactor the header to reduce code duplication:

FooBase.h

```
#ifndef __FooBase__
#define __FooBase__

namespace Ogre
{
    template<int foo, typename T> class FooBase
    {
    public:
        int getFooBase() const
        {
            return 1;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Foo.h

```
#ifndef __Foo__
#define __Foo__

#include "FooBase.h"

namespace Ogre
{
    struct FooSpecialized : public FooBase<4, double>
    {
        int getFooSpecialized() const
        {
            return 2;
        }
    };

    class FooImpl : public FooSpecialized
    {
    public:
        int getFooImpl() const
        {
            return 3;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

test.i

```
%module test

%{
#include "Foo.h"
%}

%include "FooBase.h"
%template(FooSpec) Ogre::FooBase<4,double>;
%include "Foo.h"
```

Demo (I'm set up for Python):

```
>>> import test
>>> f=test.FooImpl()
>>> f.getFooBase()
1
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. Method 2 ist no option for me because it's a third party header file. If I got it right, method 1 is just code duplication. It seems that there is no other way.